# ZWO Astronomy Camera Golang CGO

Tags: go, cgo, astronomy

I am working on a wrapper for ZWO ASI Astronomy Cameras in Golang using CGO capabilities. Please take a look at my issue here any help is appreciated: https://github.com/python-zwoasi/python-zwoasi/issues/24

Comment: You don't ask a specific question or include relevant code.  Please improve the question using the guidelines in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I’m using a mobile phone to post this, editor does not allow me to post code properly - GitHub link has everything there.